# Default Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'm unsure what the key combinations are for some of my default shortcuts. I'm aware I can just change them but I'm curious which keys would these correspond to.

*All Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Launchers*

```
Launch calculator   -> Calculator

Launch web browser  -> HomePage

Home folder         -> Explorer

Search              -> Search
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many keyboards available in the market with special "media keys" on them like 'calculator key' which when pressed would launch the calculator directly or the 'media player key' which would launch the default media player when pressed.
So these are the special launcher shortcuts that you see in keyboard setting panel.